# how to code to check internet connectivity for lollipop?

Tags: android, http

This is the code I'm deploying to check internet connection. This works perfectly for every version except Lollipop. I just got to know from few links that URL classes for lollipop version is different from the ones we were using for lower os vesions. Could please any one help me out in this matter to provide a code which works for all versions of phone.

code is:

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(4000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Why don't yoy try to reach a reliable site like Google

Answer (score 0):

For check internet Connectivity in each version of android try this:

1- Create a class with name: ConnectionDetector and copy this code

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {
private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

2 - in your activity (above onCreate method) that u want check internet connectivity copy this code

```
    Boolean _isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector _cd;
```

and in OnCreate method wherever you want to check internet connectivity use this condition:

```
     _cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
     _isInternetPresent = _cd.isConnectingToInternet();

     if (_isInternetPresent) {
         // your code that u want run if internet is connected

     } else {
         Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "Not communicate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Simple and useful ...

Answer (score 0):

i followed this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

public class ConnectionDetector {

```
private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

}

create object of that class
ConnectionDetector cd=new ConnectionDetector(context);
boolean isInternetPresent=cd.isConnectingToInternet();

Answer (score 0):

For Checking internet connection.

```
 public static void isNetworkAvailable(final Handler handler, final int timeout) {
        // ask fo message '0' (not connected) or '1' (connected) on 'handler'
        // the answer must be send before before within the 'timeout' (in milliseconds)

        new Thread() {
            private boolean responded = false;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // set 'responded' to TRUE if is able to connect with google mobile (responds fast)
                new Thread() {
                    URL aURL;
                    String link = "some link";

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      //  HttpGet requestForTest = new HttpGet("https://lit-hamlet-6856.herokuapp.com/eventsList/TECHNICAL");
                        HttpURLConnection connection;
                        try {
                            aURL = new URL(link);

                            connection = (HttpURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();
                            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            connection.connect();

                           // new DefaultHttpClient().execute(requestForTest); // can last...

                            if(connection.getResponseCode()==200)
                            responded = true;
                            Log.i(getClass().getName(),"RESULT");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(!responded && (waited < timeout)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(!responded ) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {} // do nothing
                finally {
                    if (!responded) { handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); }
                    else { handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Then call a handler to do your if internet available/non available job

```
Handler h = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()  {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if (msg.what != 1) { // code if not connected

            new NoInternetclass().execute();
        } else { // code if connected
            new Internetclass().execute();//if net is present

        }
        return  true;

    }
});
```

Then call `isNetworkAvailable(h, 3000);` from your onCreate method

Rest assured this class works as i am using this code on my nexus 4 runing 5.1.1